# Azure Web Bot Service Reset Messaging EndPoint

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

When I setup a Bot service on Azure, an end point was automatically setup. I then wanted to debug locally so I used ngrok and copied this URL into the  messaging endpoint. Stupidly, I didn't save a copy of the auto generated end point Azure provided. Now I'd like to go back to an Azure auto generated messaging endpoint however I'm unsure how to regenerate one to use. I've been informed that this is likely a security feature and to setup a new bot service again. Do I need to setup a new bot service or is there a way of regenerating a key in azure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on which type of Bot Service you created on Azure - there are two: Web App Bot and Bot Channels Registration. The latter is basically just a "registration" of a Bot in Azure + Bot Framework Services, and it's -intended- for you to host your bot wherever you like (Azure or otherwise). If you created a "Web App Bot" then it will create an Azure Web app at the same time, and the address will be based on that resource, plus an extra bit (see in a moment). To get the first part, the base address, check for the web app resource in Azure, and find it's regular Azure-generated address (I think it's like https://[whateverBotname].azurewebsites.net/). You should be able to visit that in the browser. Next is the "extra bit", which is simply the endpoint *inside* the app that the bot itself runs on (basically where the bot POST messages must go). By default its "/api/messages".

So, the full address would be https://[whateverBotname].azurewebsites.net/api/messages.

As an extra tip, if you want to change it again to test with NGrok, just paste the address in the Description field - it'll get Saved when you click the Save button.
As an extra extra tip - you can create the OTHER type of Bot - a "Bot Channels Registration" in Azure, which is JUST the registration, that you can use JUST for local development (you'll basically change the address every few hours, as your NGrok endpoint resets).

Hope that helps,

Comment: This solved my problem quickly, thanks for the extra tips!